# Zend framework on mac OSX: can I change the root Directory?

Tags: zend-framework

Zend framework on mac OSX: can I change the root Directory ?

how ?
I would like to set a directory in my home folder.

Otherwise I can only access to it by terminal

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which root directory are you talking about?  The location of the ZF libraries, or your application's root?

Either way, you can put things wherever you'd like.

For the ZF library itself, just stick it anywhere, and make sure ZendFramework-x.y.z/library is in PHP's include_path

For your application, it's just a matter of setting the DocumentRoot in your apache configuration to the public/ directory in your project.